# javascript does not want to parse text more than twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsing

So i have this function in my Js that gets called on a link onclick() event.

here is the HTML:

```
<li class="collapsed"> 
<span> 
<a href="#!" onclick="expand(this)">Directions</a> 
</span> 
<p>ajajgajajys agajgjgtajgtdja ajdtajtjate ajgdjagjd ajt</p> 
</li>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
function expand(myElem)
{           
    if (myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height<100)
        myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height="100px";
    else
        myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height="45px";
}
```

Obviosuly, the code expands the li parent tags that the links are in. Originally, the li tags are set as `height:45px;` in CSS. Then they change to `100px` and back. 
The problem im having is that the javascript only works twice. 
I cna click on the links oncde and expand the li's. Then i can click on them and collapse the li's. Then it doesn't want to work again.
I was looking at my browsers errors and i found this:

> "Error parsing value for 'height'. Declaration dropped.

After much trolling thru the interwebs I thought it might be because i'm not including the unit declarations in my js. But I am!

```
myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height="45px"; ---- as you can see.
```

*****NOTES: MY SOLUTION************

For future referance for whoever stumbles on this thread, here's my solution:

HTML --> I ened up doing somethin glike:

```
<span class="heading">
     Link1
<span>

<span class="information">
     Info about Link1
</span>

<span class="heading">
     Link2
<span>

<span class="information">
     Info about Link2
</span>
```

And the Jquery was super simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".information").hide();


     $(".heading").click(function(){
          var item = $(this);

          item.next().slideToggle(500);          
     });
});
```

...super simple, works like a charm

Comment: Use a class, toggle the class!

Comment: You don't actually have any jQuery in your sample code, but you have the jQuery tag, so here's a jQuery solution just for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/9QnD4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `replace` and `parseInt` functions like,

```
function expand(myElem)
{           
    if (parseInt(myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height.replace('px','')) < 100)
        myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height="100px";
    else
        myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height="45px";
}
```

You can use **Jquery** for simplifying it like,

**HTML**

```
<li class="collapsed"> 
  <span> 
   <a href="#!" class="direction">Directions</a> 
  </span> 
  <p>ajajgajajys agajgjgtajgtdja ajdtajtjate ajgdjagjd ajt</p> 
</li>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('.direction').on('click',function(e){
       var ht= $('.collapsed').height()==100 ? 45 : 100;
       $('.collapsed').height(ht);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (parseInt(myElem.parentNode.parentNode.style.height)<100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.
I was able to figure out that, for some reason, after the height was set the second time around to 45px, it wasn't registering as a int anymore. idk y tho. Why would it accept a declaration of 100px the first time and register it as int but not the second time? wierd.

Anyway, i tried parseInt and it worked like a charm. 
But I really like the jQuery solution that Jason P provided. the transition sold me. I'm gonna go with that.
So thanks again guys.

Comment: I'll definitely second your decision to go with Jason's solution since it puts the actual values of the sizes in the CSS, where they belong, rather than in the JS, where they don't.